# How can I quantify the phase/amplitude relationship between two signals?

Tags: signal-processing

I have two signals `A` and `B`.  I want to show that high amplitude events in `B` are phase locked to oscillations in signal `A`.  I have already identified candidate events signal `B`.

I estimate `phase_of_A` using the `angle` of the `hilbert` transform of `A`, and I estimate the `envelope_of_B` using the `abs` of the `hilbert` transform of `B`.

A scatter plot of the joint distribution shows a clear relationship between the two variables.  Additionally if I randomly re-order the `phase_of_A` variable the structure is disrupted.

My current thinking is use Monte-Carlo methods to demonstrate that the real data is more structured than the shuffled data, I'm just not sure what parameter/statistic to compute on the joint distribution.

[image]

Comment: What do the colors in you plot mean?  And what form of "quantification" do you need?  After all, the very existence of your plot shows you have a quantitative way to express the joint distribution (or an estimate thereof).  How would a "clean" way differ from that?

Comment: @whuber, the plot was generated in `matlab` using the `jet` colormap. Brighter colors indicate a higher density of observations.    Now that I think about it because phase is a circular variable I can probably fit a a von-mises distribution to the data.  Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: I don't see how you can directly fit a von Mises distribution (which is univariate) to a *bivariate* dataset. Although you state that "brighter" colors indicate greater densities, I suspect that *hue* actually represents density, with red corresponding to high and blue to low. Such color-based maps do a poor job of conveying the information. For example, it is possible that this map is showing us a bivariate distribution in which the density varies along the x-axis but the conditional density in the y direction is *constant*.

Comment: @whuber I re-wrote the question a bit, hopefully clarifying what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using two different measures.

The first was to compute the circular-linear correlation between the two variables: `phase_of_A` and `envelope_of_B`. I did this for both the real and shuffled data sets.

The second measure was to compute the mean resultant vector. The angle was the `phase_of_A` and the length was `envelope_of_B`.  These turned out to be quite sufficient for what I needed. I also did this analysis for shuffled data sets.

I was then able to compare the correlation of the real data with the distribution of correlations from the shuffled data.  Additionally I could compare the length of the mean vector for the real data with the length of the vector for the shuffled data.